# contends of div tag is printing somewhere else on webpage even it is in single div tag

Tags: php, html, css

```
 <div class="search">
 <input type="text" id="search"  placeholder="search...."/>
 <input type="button" value="search" id="serbut"onclick="goto();"/>
 </div>
```

**strong text**
my div tag contends are not arranging properly ...here i m getting different output that u wont expect ..input box at one side ...button at another side...
even not after line ...please help me how to arrange div elements ...from this situation i m aligning elements using margin property ...so many div tags are overlapped ....

Comment: `<br>` after `<input type="text" id="search"  placeholder="search...."/>
`

Comment: See that "-2" to the left? At least one of the downvotes happened for your excess usage of triple points.

Comment: Bad English is not a problem until your text is comprehensible, but your text is not. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) is a quick checklist for you.

Answer (score -1):

this might be helpful,use bootstrap Search instead of regular search.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style> 
#imaginary_container{
    margin-top:20%; /* Don't copy this */
}
.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon{
    background: white !important; 
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control{
 border-right:0; 
 box-shadow:0 0 0; 
 border-color:#ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button{
    border:0;
    background:transparent;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div id="imaginary_container"> 
                <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>  
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```